# Need Help to correct MySQL Query results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an application and I have events table. Events have types. Three types of events are supported in the application.

1. set_date (event on specific date)
2. days (event repeated on week days)
3. monthly (event on any day of a month)

Now I have a query where I am checking if the event is among any of these types and according to the type I pass values to compare with the stored values. Below is the query

`SELECT *, CASE alarm_type WHEN 'set_date' THEN FIND_IN_SET('2014-09-25',event_alarm_date)>0 WHEN 'days' THEN FIND_IN_SET('Mon',alarm_days)>0 WHEN 'monthly' THEN FIND_IN_SET('2',monthly_alarm_days)>0 END FROM events ev ORDER BY start_time`

```
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time` time NOT NULL,
  `is_repeated` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `alarm_type` enum('set_date','days','monthly') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `event_alarm_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `alarm_days` set('Sat','Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthly_alarm_days` set('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `alarm_audio` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `count_down_time` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `events`
--

INSERT INTO `events` (`id`, `event_name`, `start_time`, `end_time`, `is_repeated`, `alarm_type`, `event_alarm_date`, `alarm_days`, `monthly_alarm_days`, `alarm_audio`, `created_on`, `count_down_time`) VALUES
(1, 'Lunch Break', '10:30:45', '11:30:45', 1, 'days', NULL, 'Mon,Wed', NULL, '1411587500.mp3', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0),
(2, 'Openning Ceremony', '10:30:45', '11:30:45', 1, 'monthly', NULL, NULL, '2,3,4', '1411587568.mp3', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0),
(3, 'Inspection', '10:30:45', '12:45:30', 0, 'set_date', '2014-09-26', NULL, NULL, '1411587695.mp3', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0),
(5, 'Test2', '10:30:45', '11:30:45', 1, 'monthly', NULL, NULL, '3,4,5', '1411595801.mp3', '2014-09-24 21:56:41', 0),
(6, 'Test3', '22:20:30', '23:25:30', 1, 'days', NULL, 'Sun,Mon', NULL, '1411597086.mp3', '2014-09-24 22:18:06', 0);`
```

This query should get three rows but it gets all five rows present in the table. I have passed the date 2014-09-25 which is not present in any row but it gets a row with date 2014-09-26. Similarly I have passed 2 for monthly type and only one row has 2 entry but it gets a row that does not have entry 2. Please help correct this query. If there is any other better solution for this it will be welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're after something like this...

```
 SELECT *
   FROM events ev 

  WHERE CASE alarm_type WHEN 'set_date' THEN FIND_IN_SET('2014-09-25',event_alarm_date)>0 
                        WHEN 'days' THEN FIND_IN_SET('Mon',alarm_days) > 0 
                        WHEN 'monthly' THEN FIND_IN_SET('2',monthly_alarm_days) > 0 
        END = 1
  ORDER 
     BY start_time;
```